# How can I spark-submit with using multiple CPUs

Tags: spark-submit

I want to `spark-submit` with using multiple CPUs.

[image: top]

This is what I see when typing `top` and `1` command in my Ubuntu 16-04.

When I type
`nohup ./bin/spark-submit --class MYCLASS --master local[*] --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.3 --num-executors 2 MYJAR.jar`
I use only one core and one executor, which can be shown as

[image: executor]

Since I have 4 CPUs, I want to use 2 executors, and 2 cores per each executor. (2 * 2 = 4)

But `--num-executors` option doesn't help me. How can I do this?
Thx.

Comment: @mangusta Hmm.. I didn't change `dynamic allocation` option. And document says default value is false.

Comment: this is the anwser I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590284/number-of-executors-in-spark-local-mode

Comment: in other words, you have multiple threads (as many as cores since you have specified local[*] option) running on your local machine but they all run within a single JVM instance and they all belong to a single executor